# join or set operator which is execute faster

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT product_id FROM inventories
INTERSECT
SELECT product_id FROM order_items;

SELECT product_id FROM inventories T1
    inner join order_items t2 on T1.product_id = T2.product_id;
```

Comment: Slightly different results if duplicates. Have you compared the execution plans?

Comment: in my project i want to execute query to get data from db.which query faster using set operator ,sub query or join

Comment: Learn to use the available tools! Great knowledge for the future!

Comment: I'll just drop Eric Lippert's excellent [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) here.

Comment: THANKS  Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0):

I did few tests out of curiosity

**Summary:**
1.With out indexes ,set query is slightly in efficient when query cost and execution times are taken as parameters
2.With indexes set option is efficient than join based query when query cost,number of reads ,execution times are taken as parameters

**Demo Scripts:**

```
drop table #test2

    create table #test1
    (
    id int
    )

    create table #test2
    (
    id int
    )

    insert into #test1
    select * from numbers


insert into #test2
select * from numbers where id>10


set statistics io on


 create index nxc on #test1(id)
 create index nxc2 on #test2(id)


 select id from #test1
intersect 
select id from #test2

select 
* from 
#test1 t1
join
#test2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

**Executing two queries so many times:**

**With Indexes**

[image]

**Query cost in terms of number of reads:**

> Table '#test2______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000028'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2239, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table '#test1______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000027'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2239, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

**Query 2: using joins**

> Table '#test2______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000028'. Scan count 5, logical reads 1609, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table '#test1______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000027'. Scan count 5, logical reads 1610, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Changing  join query to use maxdop 1 and merge join hint results in same number of reads for both the queries,but query with set option is only 3% of total cost  when both are executed in parallel.

**With out indexes:**    number of reads are relatively same
[image]

**Note:**
This tests and execution plans  generated are dependant on my system based on several factors